# Delete an element on Js helper submit success?

Tags: ajax, cakephp

I have a form which submits asynchronously using the Js helper submit. Is it possible to delete an element on the success event with the js helper? Here's a snippet:

```
    echo $this->Js->submit('Submit', array(
        'url' => array('controller'=>'cmts', 'action'=>'ws', 'addCmt'),
// here's where I'd like a line to delete an element on success
// something like - 'success' => $this->Js->get('myelement')->deleteMeSomehow(),
        'update' => '#commentDiv'
    ));
```

Comment: Seems as if you can just give it a string of the javascript you'd like it to execute, so this can be done by simply writing the code in jquery (or whichever library you're using) and putting single quotes around it. For my example:

    'success' => '$("#divToRemove").remove();'

Comment: Unfortunately, stackoverflow won't let me submit my answer for another 6 hours since my rep is under 100...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems as if you can just give it a string of the javascript you'd like it to execute, so this can be done by simply writing the code in jquery (or whichever library you're using) and putting single quotes around it. For my example:

```
'success' => '$("#divToRemove").remove();'
```